# MS access between clause not Working

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

MS access between clause not Working(between 2 dates).

My query is below:

```
SELECT     [Supplier].sname, 
           [Supplier].scontact, 
           [Supplier].sadd, 
           [Purchase].qnt, 
           [Purchase].item, 
           [Purchase].price, 
           [Purchase].priceperkg, 
           [Purchase].date, 
           [Purchase].suppid, 
           [Purchase].purchaseid 
FROM       Purchase 
INNER JOIN Supplier 
ON         Purchase.suppid = Supplier.sid 
WHERE      [Purchase].date BETWEEN date= ? AND ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE      [Purchase].date BETWEEN date= ? AND ?` is not valid syntax. Try:

```
WHERE   [Purchase].date BETWEEN ? AND ?
```